# Power consumption idle vs. maxing out every core

Tags: electrical-power

Are there any rules of thumb to describe about how much more energy a server will use when its cores are completely occupied, as opposed to being idle?

Comment: What type of server?

Comment: @ewwhite - "rule of thumb", so just in general.

Comment: There's no "rule of thumb". There are only datasheets.

Answer (score 2):

High quality servers allow you to monitor this at the system hardware level.

[image]

---

So I suggest measuring your consumption using a representative workload. 
The data sheets are worst case scenarios, but are safe to use as ceiling values.

[image]